# Symfony - The mappings are inconsistent with each other

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 Entities, User and Follower.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Follower", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $followers;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Follower", mappedBy="follower")
     */
    protected $followings;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="follows")
 */
class Follower
{        
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="followers")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="followers")
     */
    protected $follower;
}
```

User have followers ($followers) and followings ($followings).

I'm not sure why, but my dev profiler says:

> The mappings AppBundle\Entity\User#followings and
>   AppBundle\Entity\Follower#follower are inconsistent with each other.
>
> The mappings AppBundle\Entity\Follower#follower and
>   AppBundle\Entity\User#followers are inconsistent with each other.

Why they are incosistent and it should be done?

Comment: I think it's completely wrong schema... I guess that better create entity `user` and entity `follow`, and in `follow` use `who` as `user.id` and whom as `user.id`...
I'm sure that it will be much better and transparent... and you can easy join tables to receive following and followers...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the Follower Entity, replace this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="followers")
 */
protected $follower;
```

with:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="followings")
 */
protected $follower;
```

You can use the command doctrine:schema:validate that checks the current mapping  for valid forward and reverse mappings.

> php app/console doctrine:schema:validate

Hope this help

Comment: For me it was `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

Comment: hi @DanChaltiel.  Thanks for the contribution.  You are referring on the folder structure of the version 3 of the framework. This is an old answer about the v2.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace followers by followings in :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="followers")
 */
protected $follower;
```

But i think it's better to use ManyToMany associations on User Entity. You can try something like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="followings")
  */
  private $followers;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="followers")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="follows",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="following_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="follower_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   *      )
  */
  private $followings;
```